# Why is there a stylelint error in css file that doesn't make sense?

Tags: css, node.js, stylelint

I'm running `stylelint` on my files and this is the last error I'm left with:

```
1:1  ✖  Unknown rule function-calc-no-invalid  function-calc-no-invalid
```

The first line:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700,900');
```

I need troubleshooting here, but I'm clueless. It's my first time asking question here so please excuse if my forum manners are little out of sync.

I'm running `stylelint --fix styles.css` and don't expect any errors now.

Comment: The rule "function-calc-no-invalid" is not a built-in stylelint rule, and it seems like there might be a typo.

Comment: Thats what chatgpt told me . but the issue is still there. I have deleted that import line . But the issue is still there. Even my branch is not showing in workflows and I am wondering why

Comment: lol, why everyone thinks that I'm ChatGPT, anyway, go to [Migrating to 14.0.0](https://stylelint.io/migration-guide/to-14/#users), you would see it says *the `function-calc-no-invalid rule` was removed*. And, probably you're using a version higher than 14.0.0, no?

Answer (score 3):

As of 14.0.0, support for this rule has been removed due to a security vulnerability.

https://stylelint.io/migration-guide/to-14/#function-calc-no-invalid-rule

> The function-calc-no-invalid has been removed. You should remove it from your configuration object.

Comment: Removing it from your configuration object usually involves updating any shared configs you're using, e.g. stylelint-config-standard. Perhaps add that to your answer?